# Mechanism for reaction of an allene with the Grignard Reagent(RMgX)

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organometallic-compounds, grignard-reagent

How does the Grignard Reagent($\ce{RMgX}$) react with an allene $\ce{CH_2=C=CH_2}$ and what are the products formed?

This is exactly what I tried to do.

[image: Reaction mechanism]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Consider the stability of potential carbanions.

Comment: @Mithoron I very well know how Grignard reagent reacts with a ketone, but that certainly doesn't me help here.

Comment: Well, I think it should at least give you good idea. If it doesn't react in a very similar way then it would be tricky question, but  Weijun Zhou seems to think ^^^ the same.

Comment: I think it's fine. You didn't say that it will later be treated with $\ce{H3O+}$ though so that is probably another step, not part of the mechanism of the reaction with $\ce{RMgX}$.

Comment: @WeijunZhou in almost all the reactions of Grignard reagent, the compound is finally treated with dilute $H_3O^+$

Comment: So that's it...what I did is the only way for Grignard reagent to react with an allene?

Comment: Why do you think these react at all?

Comment: @Zhe I have no idea. Our teacher once told us to predict the reaction mechanism. Will they not react?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, but I haven't worked with allenes much. There are really only two pathways to look at. Deprotonation, which you've looked at, and migratory insertion.

Comment: @Zhe can you show the second one(migratory insertion) please?

Comment: Look up migratory insertion on wikipedia and then scroll down to where C-C double bonds are involved. I don't think this is very likely with just magnesium though...

Comment: @zhe I found a new way, I'll have to answer my own question...tell me if you think it's correct..